# How to add Cross Origin Filter for Jetty in GeoServer on Mac

Tags: geoserver, jetty

I want to add an **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*** to the response from GeoServer because I need to download images from another domain. Instead of building a proxy, I prefer to use [Cross Origin Filter](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter) of Jetty(GeoServer's Web Server) to achieve this. However, I don't know how to set it up in GeoServer.

1. My GeoServer's version is 2.1.3 so the Jetty's version is 6, which does not include the jetty-servlets.jar.
2. I downloaded the **jetty-servlets-8.1.5.v20120716.jar** from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/8.1.5.v20120716/) and renamed it to **jetty-servlets.jar**, then put it into `/Applications/GeoServer.app/Contents/Resources/Java/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/`
3. Then I add the following codes to the web.xml file at `/Applications/GeoServer.app/Contents/Resources/Java/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml`

`<filter>   <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>   <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>   </filter>   <filter-mapping>   <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   </filter-mapping>`

At last, I restarted GeoServer but the page at `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web` showed me an error 404:

HTTP ERROR: 404
NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/geoserver/web
Powered by jetty://

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: I just had your code <filter> <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name> <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class> </filter> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping> and i have the same mitake : ERROR 503 !

Comment: look at the jetty log.
I think you sould also add jetty-util lib

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that you can add random jars to your jetty install and expect it to work - which seems to be case here.

The easiest solution (if you really can't be bothered to add a proxy script) is to download the [latest version of jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Downloading+Jetty) and add the [GeoServer war](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/geoserver/geoserver-2.1.4-war.zip) file to it and then modify the web.xml file.

Comment: I downloaded [jetty-distribution-8.1.5.v20120716.tar.gz](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/dist/) and added the [GeoServer 2.1.4 war](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/geoserver/geoserver-2.1.4-war.zip) to the `webapps` folder. After I started Jetty, other apps like "test" and "spdy" could run very well but the "geoserver" could not run, which showed me an Error 503. Does the GeoServer needs other settings? I'm a newbie of GIS and I just feel that use proxy is not an elegant way, so could you provide more detail steps? Thank you very much!

Comment: you can use tomcat +apache