# Problem Access-Control-Allow-Origin.GeoServer ISS OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, asp.net

I use OpenLyaers in order to show france Departements. My website is generated in ASP .NET MVC 4 (i use Visual studio 2012) ans i use GeoServer to store WFS files.

I want to access to my WFS layer by

```
var wfs =  new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("States", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
                featureType: "states",
                featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
            })
            });


map.addLayer(wfs);
```

In Google Chrome console i have :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms. Origin http://localhost:50431 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How i can parametre Geoserver to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to do some cross-domain request, qhich are denied by default as defined by the [Same origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).
There are 2 solutions:

1. For debug only, you can start chrome with the option:

   chrome.exe --disable-web-security
2. The modern browser allow cross-domain ajax if the server add a particular header in the response. Now it depends under which server Geoserver is running. If it's jetty, you can allow cross-domain as described in the [Jetty wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Geoserver run with jetty (i have Geoserver 2.4 installed with windows installer). 

I did what it is explained in the jetty Wiki but Now i have this mistake when i want to open the geoserver page :

    HTTP ERROR: 503

    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
    RequestURI=/geoserver/web/

    Powered by jetty://

Maybe i havent' get the good jetty-servlets.jar in the good directory. How i can know which choose and where place it ?

Comment: @ROCHEDY try this link <http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32407/how-to-add-cross-origin-filter-for-jetty-in-geoserver-on-mac>